# How can create a panel in left and right side of main frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I want to create a panel in the left side of main frame and a panel in the right side of main frame.

```
----------------------------------------
| left panel |  jframe  |  right panel |
|            |          |              |
----------------------------------------
```

The left and right panel will be expand/contract functionality.

Comment: Create a `JFrame` as your window, then give it the right layoutmanager (Maybe a `BorderLayout` by using center/east/west? see http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/swinglayoutmanagement/ and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html for some options), then add your three `JPanel`s.

Answer (score 2):

No, they'll be JPanel (for swing)

Using BorderLayouut and panels left and right and center you'd code:

```
getContentPane ().add (left, BorderLayout.WEST);
getContentPane ().add (center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
getContentPane ().add (right, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

Comment: Left and right panel will have expand/contract functionality?

Comment: Have a look at JSplitPane maybe?